What will influence the actual unix timestamp I get when I retrieve a timestamp field through jdbc from MySQL?
My ultimate goal is to retrieve the UTC time or unix time from datetime, timestamp and date field. From what I have read, the timestamp is already stored as UTC time, and date and datetime are like some plain text representations which do not have time zone info.
So, at first I thought if I retrieve a timestamp field from database, the internal value I get will not change no matter how the host computer or client computer's time zone change. And, for date and datetime, their values will change according to client's time zone.
But when I test it, it's different from what I've thought:
The table schema is simple, the column names indicate the column type, so I will skip to INSERT statement:
INSERT INTO t_time (f_timestamp, f_datetime, f_date)
VALUES (
    '2024-04-17 20:30:00',
    '2024-04-17 20:30:00',
    '2024-04-17'
);

I executed SELECT * FROM t_time on the server, I got:



f_timestamp
f_datetime
f_date




2024-04-17 20:30:00
2024-04-17 20:30:00
2024-04-17



Then I retrieved the above row using JDBC, with 3 calls to getObject(N, java.sql.Timestamp.class), when my client computer has a time zone of +8, this is what I get (use getTime() on java.util.Date):
timestamp   1713357000000
datetime    1713357000000
date        1713283200000

But after I changed my client computer's time zone to +9, the timestamp changed:
timestamp   1713353400000
datetime    1713353400000
date        1713279600000

I can understand the change of date and datetime, but why timestamp is also changed? Shouldn't it be an 'absolute' value?
According to mysql 5.7 doc:

MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)

It says there is a conversion, but why this conversion will change the unix timestamp I get?

In 2038 timestamp will reach it's date storage upper limit and you application will stop working.  Happy 2038 to you.
